# Can Interactivity reset popup view model every time triggered?

Tags: c#, prism

Is Interactivity the best way to show new Window? If so how can I reset/re-init ViewModel of my UserControl? Because I see it reuses popup.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you are doing in this particular Interactivity? Is this asking the end user for a simple yes/no, or are you allowing them to edit data, its it a search/find UI, or something else?

Comment: I'm trying to clear 2 listboxes so next time that window shows, those boxes are clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ViewModel for you Interaction Request, there should be a property named Notification. That gets set each time the request is called. Add some logic there to clear the list boxes.
See below:

```
public INotification Notification
{
    get
    {
        return notification;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value is ItemSelectionNotification)
        {
            notification = value as ItemSelectionNotification;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Notification);
            //*** Add ListBox clearing code here!!
            // Maybe a call to a method -> ClearListBoxes();
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my ItemSelectionNotification class looks like in case you need it.

```
public class ItemSelectionNotification : Confirmation
{
    public ItemSelectionNotification() { }
    public ItemSelectionNotification(object payload)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    }
    public object SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public object Payload { get; } = null;
}
```